# Can the elasticity of a concave function be strictly increasing

Tags: calculus

If a real valued function $f$ defined on the positive orthant is strictly concave, can its elasticity, defined as:

$$E(f(x))=\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}$$

be strictly increasing in $x$?

Comment: does this mean if $x_1>x_2$ then $E(f(x_1))>E(f(x_2))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x+1}$. Then $f$ is strictly concave on $(0,\infty)$. Furthermore,
$$(Ef)(x) = \frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{x\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}}}{\sqrt{x+1}} = \frac{x}{2(x+1)} = \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)$$
is strictly increasing on $(0,\infty)$.